# An underscore on the right hand of generator

Tags: scala, for-loop

In the snippet of the Scala code below it uses an underscore on the right hand side of the generator (<-) in the for loop.  "for ((bb1, idx1) <- _)"
I cant seem to figure out how it works because similar examples I tried in the REPL give me errors.  Thanks!

```
    if (!useful(bb)(idx)) {
      useful(bb) += idx
      dropOf.get((bb, idx)) foreach {
        for ((bb1, idx1) <- _) {

          debuglog("\tAdding: " + bb1(idx1) + " to the worklist, as a useful DROP.")
          worklist += ((bb1, idx1))
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nothing special with the for-comprehension itself. I can't say exactly *what* that example is doing, because I don't know what the types are, but the expression within `foreach` is just an anonymous function simplified by the underscore syntax.

For example:

```
List(Some((1, 2)), Some((3, 4)), Some((5, 6))) foreach {
    for((a, b) <- _) {
        println(s"a: $a - b: $b")
    }
}
```

De-sugars to:

```
List(Some((1, 2)), Some((3, 4)), Some((5, 6))) foreach { pairOpt =>
    pairOpt foreach { case (a, b) =>
        println(s"a: $a - b: $b")
    }
}
```

The underscore in the above case is a placeholder for the `Option[(Int, Int)]` within the `List`.

Comment: O thanks, I tried something like your example but instead of using Some(1,2) I did (1,2) which gave me errors.